# Mobile Angular UI Tab style not applied when inside ng-repear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

When creating a tabbed control using mobile-angular-ui (http://mobileangularui.com/demo/#/tabs), everything works fine UNTIL I need to create the tabs dynamically.

So if I take the following code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ui-state='activeTab' ui-default='1'>
  <li ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 1}">
    <a ui-set="{'activeTab': 1}">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 2}">
    <a ui-set="{'activeTab': 2}">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 3}">
    <a ui-set="{'activeTab': 3}">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Everything if fine. However, if I add the following in:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ui-state='activeTab' ui-default='1'>
   <div ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">
      <li ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 1}">
        <a ui-set="{'activeTab': 1}">{{tab}}</a>
      </li>
   </div>
    </ul>
```

The correct tabs are drawn but they have none of the styles and just appear as unstyled 's

How to I get Mobile Angular UI to reapply the styles (or at least draw it right first time).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li ng-repeat="wl in watchlist" ui-class="{'active': activeTab == {{wl.index}}}" ng-click="selectedWatchlistTab(wl)">
     <a ui-set="{'activeTab': {{wl.index}}}">{{wl.name}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

> Above code should work for you.
>
> watchlist = [{name:watchlist1,index:0},{name:watchlist2,index:1},{name:watchlist3,index:3}]

[Tabs - Angular UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngMDf.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because by introducing a DIV element that sits between ul.nav and the descendent li's, you are changing the structure of the HTML, which makes the CSS styling rules no longer apply.

http://mobileangularui.com/demo/#/tabs source:

```
<div class="btn-group justified nav-tabs">
  <a class="btn btn-default active" ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 1}" ui-set="{'activeTab': 1}">Tab 1</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 2}" ui-set="{'activeTab': 2}">Tab 2</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 3}" ui-set="{'activeTab': 3}">Tab 3</a>
```

and its CSS:

```
.btn-group > .btn-default.active, .btn-group > .btn-default.active:focus {
  background-color: #007aff;
  border-color: #006ee6;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Instead of having a separate "div" with ng-repeat on it, move the ng-repeat into "li" itself:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ui-state='activeTab' ui-default='1'>
  <li ng-repeat="tab in allTabs" ui-class="{'active': activeTab == 1}">
    <a ui-set="{'activeTab': 1}">{{tab}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```